# What do the CIE Standard Illuminants SPDs represent?

Tags: optics, visible-light, radiometry, photometry

The CIE publishes the relative SPD for standard illuminants. I was curious what photometric quantity it represents i.e. radiance or irradiance or something else.

I was reading the "Intro the Radiometry and Photometry" textbook by McCluney. It mentioned the following:

> The CIE defines an illuminant as "Radiation with a relative SPD defined over a wavelength range that influences object color perception". It is emphasized that an illuminant is a numerically defined spectral distribution of radiant flux. (It may be a spectral irradiance or spectral radiance.)

I saw one other source, where the D65 SPD was read in and converted into Luminance by using the luminance formula

> L_v = 683 * Integral(SPD*V_lambda dlambda)

Does that mean the SPD is spectral radiance?

The same question applies to the XYZ and RGB color matching functions.

Any inputs will be really appreciated.

Comment: SPD = Spectral Power Distribution. Power is $Watts$. Radiance is $Watts/(m^2*steradian)$. For more, see https://luminusdevices.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403685063437-What-do-CCT-CIE-and-SPD-mean-in-LED-lighting-

Comment: Thanks for providing this link. Just to confirm, the SPD's represent the Radiant Flux (measured in Watts) of the illuminants. I am stating this based on the following statements in the SPD section of link:
SPD is a measurement of the energy (in Watts) that is output by the source as a function of wavelength.
AND
The radiant flux characteristics of light sources are typically represented with an SPD graph: wavelengths on X-axis, and spectral power (radiant flux) on Y-axis.

Comment: The link also states "the entire electromagnetic output of a source is described in terms of radiance – energy output". 

I have seen SPDs typically written as relative SPD and the plots have different limits for the Y-axis. Does this scale factor influence the physical quantity it represents.